# LDAP (JNDI Realm) authentication with apache tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

we are trying to achieve tomcat authentication with LDAP setting below is m, trying to configure server.xml with below code

```
<Host ....      
<Realm   className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
         connectionName="cn=ApacheDS,dc=example,dc=com"
         connectionPassword="secret"
         connectionURL="ldap://localhost:10389"
         roleBase="dc=example,dc=com,dc=ActiveMQ"
         roleName="cn"
         roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
         roleSubtree="false"
         userPassword="userPassword"
         userPattern="cn={0},dc=example,dc=com"
    />
</Host>
```

in web.xml I have configured groups

```xml
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Entry points</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/analyze/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/common/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/compose/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/content/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/custom/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/explore/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/home/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/layouts/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/partials/*</url-pattern>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>rtsAdministrator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

In ldap we are making use of partition `dc=example,dc=com` and connection name ApacheDS, under partition i have created `ou=ActiveMQ` under that `oU=Group` and `oU=User` under this we have users, but when i incorporated this change i am getting following error in ApacheDS(LDAP server) console.

I am getting following error in LDAP server console

```
[15:25:15] ERROR [org.apache.directory.server.core.authn.AbstractAuthenticator] - 
ERR_6 Authentication error : Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: cn=ApacheDS,dc=example,dc=com
```

can anybody tell me what could be the issue. Let me know if you need any more information.

It'd be helpful if anybody can give me solution for my problem.

Comment: i found the answer, below link provides end to end configuration steps http://www.flashguides.co.uk/guide/Setting_up_a_DIT_in_Apache_Directory                                                                                                                         http://www.flashguides.co.uk/guide/Using_Apache_DS_with_Tomcat

Answer (score 3):

Your LDAP DIT isn't rooted at `dc=example,dc=com`, and it would be surprising if it was. That's only an example configuration. Find out its real root and use that instead.

You also have `dc=example,dc=com,dc=ActiveMQ`, which proves the point. This must also be wrong, but for a different reason: it's out of order. You wouldn't have `dc=ActiveMQ` as the root-most element in a DN.

Sounds like you have some investigating to do.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, can please elaborate little more, if i expand  LDAP browser i could see heirarchy as DIT->Root DSE->dc=example,dc=com->ou=ActiveMQ->ou=Group also ou=ActiveMQ we have created ou=User. under ou=Group we have created groups and under ou=User we are created list of users and under connections tab i have created connection by name ApaacheDS. Let me know what else i need to incorporate

Comment: I can't make head or tail of the hierarchy you have posted, because you've posted it as a comment instead of in your question where it belongs, and where it could have been formatted intelligibly.